# apache giraph: java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: hadoop, giraph

I have been trying to run an Apache Giraph job on an Ubuntu server with Hadoop 2.7.3 and Giraph 1.3.0. I have also tried to run the same job on Hadoop 2.6 with lower versions of Giraph (1.2/1.1). But I receive the following error in both the situations.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.setPingInterval(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;I)V from class org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphJob

at org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphJob.run(GiraphJob.java:213)
at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.run(GiraphRunner.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.main(GiraphRunner.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Has anybody experienced a similar situation ?

Answer (score 0):

its because of your hadoop version, the access modifier of `setPingInterval()` method has been changed in hadoop 2.6.0, degrade your hadoop version to 2.5.1 and it will work fine.